# Usage of tensorflow One Hot Encodings

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

​I'm getting a AssertionError for this fuction ... how do i resolve this

```
def one_hot_matrix(label, depth=6):
     one_hot = tf.one_hot(label, depth, axis = 0)
     one_hot = tf.reshape(one_hot, (-1,1))
     return one_hot
def one_hot_matrix_test(target):
    label = tf.constant(1)
    depth = 4
    result = target(label, depth)
    print("Test 1:",result)
    assert result.shape[0] == depth, "Use the parameter depth"
    assert np.allclose(result, [0., 1. ,0., 0.] ), "Wrong output. Use tf.one_hot"
     label_2 = [2]
    result = target(label_2, depth)
    print("Test 2:", result)
    assert result.shape[0] == depth, "Use the parameter depth"
    assert np.allclose(result, [0., 0. ,1., 0.] ), "Wrong output. Use tf.reshape as instructed" 
    print("\033[92mAll test passed")
```

​

Comment: Please provide some example inputs and the error.

Comment: Hi! Please provide complete code and error details which will help us understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly you got an assertion error according to the shape of the result. 
For that insure you use

```
one_hot = tf.reshape(one_hot, (depth,))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
one_hot=tf.reshape(tf.one_hot(label, depth, axis = 0), [4,])
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the shape attribute, no value after the decimal point

```py
one_hot = tf.reshape(tf.one_hot(label, depth, axis=0), shape=[depth,])
```